# How does peer to peer communication work without port mapping

Tags: bittorrent

How can BitTorrent client programs connect to each other when both are behind a router?

My understanding was that to open a socket connection to another computer one had to do port mapping on the router. But this is not the case with something like BitTorrent. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically not a problem that they are behind a router; everything on the Internet is behind several routers. It's the *network address translation* (NAT) that causes problems with peer-to-peer protocols.

There are NAT traversal techniques like [TCP hole punching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) and [UDP hole punching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching). You could read more e.g. on [Developing P2P Protocols across NAT](http://www.forcalsoft.eu/public/documenti/112/1489164793elj2006-148-P2P-NAT.pdf) by Girish Venkatachalam; it even has a practical example.